# reflection on all ember data models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my app I want to create an interface to the server database. That's why I'm looking for a list of all models I defined in the app.

Example:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:DS.attr('string')
)};

App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    .
    .
    .
});
App.ModelA = DS.Model.extend({
    .
    .
    .
});
and so on...
```

Now I'm lookin for a list which contains each Model.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-models/

Comment: @BogdanM. Thx, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a list on the client which contains all Models and not the records in a model. At the end i will use Model.find(), but first I need all Models in a list to iterate over them.

Comment: I added an answer to finish the idea.

Comment: Thx! Just reading it sounds correct, but I cannot test it now. When I'm home I'll test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var property in App){ 
 //if property is extending DS.Model
 if (App[property] && App[property].superclass && App[property].superclass === DS.Model) 
  App[property].find(); //get all instances
};
```